# KDE (kernel density estimation) of Matrix with 13 dimensions using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I keep getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Dropbox/Public/Data Processor/src/dP.py", line 69, in <module>
    gkde = stats.gaussian_kde(kdeData)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 86, in
__init__
    self._compute_covariance()   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 339, in
_compute_covariance
    self.inv_cov = linalg.inv(self.covariance)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 327, in inv
    raise LinAlgError("singular matrix") numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

I'm not sure how this applies to my data. It's a huge wall of text but if it helps to at least see what context the code is being applied in here it is http://pastebin.com/Myx5TpYy. Each matrix has 12 data points in it, to be honest I'm not sure if I'll need all the data points but I think getting to know what's going wrong here will help me out either way.
 Here is the code I've been trying to get to work

```
from decimal import *  
import csv  
import numpy as np  
from scipy import stats  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

matrix = [] 
col1 = [] 
col2 = [] 
col3 = [] 
col4 = [] 
col5 = [] 
col6 = [] 
col7 = [] 
col8 = [] 
col9 = [] 
col10 = [] 
col11 = [] 
col12 = []


for line in open("data.txt", "r"):
    col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_9, col_10, col_11, col_12 = line.split()

    col_1_val = col_1[:]
    col_2_val = col_2[:]
    col_3_val = col_3[:]
    col_4_val = col_4[:]
    col_5_val = col_5[:]
    col_6_val = col_6[:]
    col_7_val = col_7[:]
    col_8_val = col_8[:]
    col_9_val = col_9[:]
    col_10_val = col_10[:]
    col_11_val = col_11[:]
    col_12_val = col_12[:]

    matrix.append([Decimal(col_1_val), Decimal(col_2_val), Decimal(col_3_val), Decimal(col_4_val), Decimal(col_5_val), Decimal(col_6_val), Decimal(col_7_val), Decimal(col_8_val), Decimal(col_8_val), Decimal(col_9_val), Decimal(col_10_val), Decimal(col_11_val), Decimal(col_12_val)])

kdeData = np.array(matrix).T  
print kdeData
gkde = stats.gaussian_kde(kdeData)
ind = np.linspace(-13,13,512) 
kdepdf = gkde.evaluate(matrix)
plt.figure()
plt.hist(xn, bins=20, normed=1)
plt.plot(ind, stats.norm.pdf(ind), color="r", label='DGP normal')
plt.plot(in, kdepdf, label='kde', color="g") plt.title('Kernel Density Estimation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of the `data.txt` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are two completely zero columns in the input matrix. This produces a big band of zeros in the internal covariance matrix calculated by `gaussian_kde`, making it singular and causing the routine to fail.

If I rewrite your example like this:

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy import stats  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

valid=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11]
matrix=np.loadtxt('data.txt',skiprows=1,usecols=valid)
kdeData = np.array(matrix).T  
print kdeData
gkde = stats.gaussian_kde(kdeData)
ind = np.linspace(-13,13,512)
kdepdf = gkde.evaluate(kdeData)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(ind, stats.norm.pdf(ind), color="r", label='DGP normal')
plt.plot(ind, kdepdf, label='kde', color="g")
plt.title('Kernel Density Estimation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It works:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, you are doing far, far too much work to get the matrix. Replace everything from the line `matrix = []` to the end of the for loop with:

```
matrix = []

for line in open("data.txt", "r"):
    matrix.append([Decimal(e) for e in line[:-1].split()])
```

Secondly, the reason for the "singular matrix" error depends entirely on your data. For example, do you have a row of entirely the same value (say, all 0's or all 1's)? Alternatively, do you have two rows that are identical? Either of these would lead to this problem using the kernel density estimator.